# Excel VBA error management

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, runtime-error

I read [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1038024/on-error-resume-next-not-working) on error handling, but when I try to replicate even a simple error management scenario it won't work. I'm trying to run the following modified code from one of the examples:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim n As Variant

    On Error GoTo nx

    For i = 1 To 10
        n = 1 / 0 'this WILL cause an error.
    label1:
    Next i

Exit Sub

    nx:
    n = 5
    Resume label1

End Sub
```

The code looks good but when I actually run it, I get `run-time error 11: division by zero` in a pop up window.

Can someone help me understand this or point me to the right direction?

Comment: As with Richard, this runs fine for me. Do you use the `Option Explicit` directive? It will throw errors for undeclared variables, which helps weed out errors due to tpyos. It also will force you to declare all variables, which is probably a Good Thing anyway. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine for me and doesn't throw up any errors. I even walked through it line by line using the debugger and nothing untoward happened.

As a minor point, I find the following alternative much clearer to understand:

```
Sub Example()

    Dim n As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To 10
        n = 1 / 0 'this WILL cause an error.
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then n = 5
    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

However that is just personal preference.

Comment: I just tried running your code, same error keeps popping up on this line: `n = 1 / 0 'this WILL cause an error.`

Comment: That's odd. For me the `On Error Resume Next` means that an error isn't displayed after `n = 1 / 0` but `Err.Number` now equals `11` (division by zero). As a result `Err.Number <> 0` is true so `n` is set to `5` and the code continues the loop. You may want to try re-installing Excel.

Comment: This is a work computer, so I'm not entirely sure if that's an implemented feature or break... It's still getting me frustrated because for me to continue developing and writing my code I need to handle errors and exceptions effectively. I just sent an email to my IT peeps, let's see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was, when reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783616/how-do-i-pass-a-raised-error-to-a-custom-error-handler-in-vba). On the options menu my settings were set by default on "Break on all errors" instead of "break on unhandled errors". Easy enough fix, but I still have another issue with my excel breaking with any instance of `err.[arg]`. I get a `Compile error: Expected Function or Variable`.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Super User is not a forum where you can add new questions to a thread. A new question belongs in, well, a new question. Please edit this answer to remove the additional question. Feel free to provide a link to this related question in your new question.

Answer (score -1):

You code traps the error then just keeps going. Try it like this and maybe you`'ll see a bit better what happens with it:

```
Sub Example()
Dim n As Variant

On Error GoTo nx

For i = 1 To 10
    n = 1 / 0 'this WILL cause an error.
    label1:
        Next i

Debug.print "loop done"

Exit Sub

nx:
    Debug.print "error called", i
    n = 5
    Resume label1

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it, same error pop-up came up from the offending line. I'm beginning to think that it's somehow my excel acting up, but I'm not entirely sure.